# Given $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)-z|^{4/3} \le 1 + 3|f(z)-z|^{6/5}$ find $f'(-i)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a differentiable function such that $|f(z)-z|^{4/3} \le 1 + 3|f(z)-z|^{6/5}$. Find $f'(-i)$.

My attempt:

$\frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}-1}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}} \le 3$

$\frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}} \le \frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}-1}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}} \le 3$

$|f(z)-z|^{2/15} \le 3$

$|f(z)-z| \le 3^{15/2}$

Let $g(z)=f(z)-z$. By Liouville's theorem $g(z)$ is constant. Therefore $f(z)=z$.

Then $f'(z)=1$ and $f'(-i)=1$.

Professor said that my answer is correct but my solution is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where does$$\frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}} \leqslant\frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}-1}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}}$$come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your solution is incorrect because the estimate
$$
\frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}} \le \frac{|f(z)-z|^{4/3}-1}{|f(z)-z|^{6/5}}
$$
does not hold. Also your conclusion $f(z) = z$ is wrong, one only gets that $f(z) -z$ is constant.

An upper bound for the absolute value of  $g(z) = f(z) - z$ can be obtained as follows: If $|g(z)| > 1$ then
$$
 |g(z)|^{4/3}  \le 1 + 3 |g(z)|^{6/5} \le 4 |g(z)|^{6/5} \\
\implies |g(z)| \le 4^{15/2} \, .
$$
It follows that $|g(z)| \le 4^{15/2}$ for *all* $z \in \Bbb C$, so that
so that $g$ is constant by Liouville's theorem. Therefore
$$
 0 = g'(z) = f'(z) - 1
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb C$.